# Logcat displays Activity idle timeout

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout

Been working on this issue for a number of days and I can't for the life of me determine whats causing it. I've tried placing breakpoints all over the place. Stepping through the code. I can't see anywhere in my code where I screwed something up. When debugging the application, the only irregular logcat output takes place while launching a second activity. In the emulator the screen goes black, and the application hangs. Logcat's final few lines display:

```
I/ActivityManager(   59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.testapp/.result    
W/ActivityManager(   59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(   59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45048110 com.test/.result}
```

Obviously I've done something wrong with the way I'm calling the second activity, so I figured I'd just display everything I've written specific to that point and see if anyone in the community can see something I'm missing.

Application manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.manskills"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".testapp"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".result"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

The portion of my code which is calling the second activity is as follows:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            String cat = lv.getAdapter().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(testapp.this, result.class );
            i.putExtra("category", cat);
            i.putExtra("skill", lv.getSelectedItemPosition());
            testapp.this.startActivity(i);
        }
     }
```

And the second activity class is contained in a separate java file as follows:

```
public class result extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
    TextView tv_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skill_title);
    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.skill_pic1);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skill_text1);
    Bundle bund = getIntent().getExtras();
    String cat = bund.getString("category");
    int skill = bund.getInt("skill");  }
```

The xml layout file for the second activity is a simple relative layout with some text views and image views. I'm lost in the sauce here as to what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone point anything out?

Comment: Are you doing any thread work.  It looks like there is a wait on an object that is timing out.  Do you have a wait() or synchronized anywhere?

Comment: You may want to check onResume of result...